# WordPress preventing form resubmission

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I'm working on the code below experimentally.
Technically I created a custom page inside a form that changes the description of the site.

- Here I am processing data with REST API via form.

Everything seems fine. But if I submitted the form once, I get the warning **"Confirm resubmit the form"** later. Of course, this is very natural.

I researched some methods to solve this problem.

```
$ POST -> REDIRECT -> $ GET
```

Technically I found that using the above methodology is a general solution.

But the solutions are usually like this `redirect -> url/?success=true` or `false` where I can't convey messages that I can post about error or success.

I don't want to pass the messages as parameters.

```
url/?success=true&message=form%20saved
```

Isn't there any way I can send it as `$args` instead?

The best example of this is the [WordPress get template parts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/#parameters) function. The last parameter of this function accepts an argument.

The `wp_safe_redirect` or `wp_redirect` function does not accept arguments. How can I solve this problem? Maybe I'm following a very wrong path. I am waiting for your solutions.

#### Here's my snippet of code I'm talking about

**localhost/admin** `admin.php` page template

```php
<?php

/* Template Name: Admin */

get_template_part('admin-parts/core');

get_header();

get_template_part('admin-parts/layout');

get_footer(); ?>
```

**core.php**

```php
<?php

function api_request($api_url = null, $params = null, $method = 'GET')
{
    if (!$api_url){
        return new WP_Error('no_api_url',"Missing API URL");
    }

    //Create request
    $request = WP_REST_Request::from_url( $api_url );

    //Method
    $request->set_method( $method );

    //params
    switch($method){
        case 'GET':
        $request->set_query_params($params);
        break;
        case 'POST':
        $request->set_body_params($params);
        break;
    }

    //Get response
    $response = rest_do_request( $request );

    if ( $response->is_error() ) {
        return $response->as_error();
    }

    //Get datas
    $datas = $response->get_data();

    return $datas;
}

$APIbase = get_rest_url();

$result = isset($_POST['description']) ? api_request($APIbase.'wp/v2/settings', array('description' => $_POST['description']), 'POST') : null;

if ( $result ) {
    wp_safe_redirect( esc_url( get_permalink() ) );
    exit;
}
?>
```

**layout.php**

```html
<form method="POST">

    <div class="entry-content">
        <p>
            <?php echo $result !== null ? is_wp_error($result) ? $result->get_error_message() : "Success" : ""; ?>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input name="description" type="text" value="<?php echo get_bloginfo('description'); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </p>
    </div>

</form>
```

[image]

> If the page is refreshed after submitting the form, the dialog appears.

Comment: "Confirm resubmit the form" When, where and why?

Comment: You could submit your form over AJAX instead of using a form post.